# Enabling Equal Cost Multi-path in Ubuntu

Tags: router, routing

How do I enable Equal Cost Multi-path on the Linux kernel in Ubuntu? I want multiple routes to be concurrently present in my routing table.
I was following this guide: http://brezular.com/2011/11/13/part1-recompiling-linux-microcore-4-0-2-for-equal-cost-routes/

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you [edit] this question to make it [on topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) for our site?

Comment: @ElderGeek Done sir